# Nvidia rendering on Docker

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, docker

I have an ubuntu 20.04 server with nvidia drivers up and running. The server is headless. If I run `nvidia-smi` on the host machine, I get

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   35C    P8    16W / 250W |     51MiB / 12192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       963      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 49MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and if I run `glxgears -display 0` I can through nvidia-smi that the GPU is working. Great! Now I want to do exactly the same thing on a docker machine! As an example, I will use the standard nvidia-docker image:

`sudo docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=:0 --rm --gpus all --entrypoint /bin/bash -it nvidia/cuda:11.0-base`

in the docker container, I get glxgears:
`apt update apt install mesa-utils -y`

However, nvidia-smi here doesn't look as good:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN X (Pascal)    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   34C    P8    16W / 250W |     51MiB / 12192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And in fact `glxgears` doesn't work:

```
root@75776a0b57b1:/# glxgears -display :0
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `nvidia/cudagl:11.0-base` image instead of `nvidia/cuda:11.0-base` to leverage NVIDIA's opengl support libraries.